# What was special about the Avengers: Endgame post-credit scene?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the re-release of "Avengers: Endgame" after the end credits Anthony Russo announces the post credit scene which in this case was a deleted scene. He mentioned that they loved that scene but it just had to be cut due to already long running time of the movie. So they were really happy to be able to include it in the movie this way - as a post credit scene.

In this scene we see:

> Hulk saving some people from a fire in a high-rise and then receiving a phone call. When he answers the phone, he listens and then says "Steve?".

I did not get it AT ALL. What was so special about out? What does it mean? Why it was worth including in the movie?

Comment: It wasn't worth including in the movie. That's why it was deleted.

Comment: @OrangeDog But they DID include it in the movie after all, as a post credit scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was not worthy being in the movie**

Endgame writers explained this in an [interview for the LA Times](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/05/05/avengers-endgame-writers-reveal-dropped-hero-hulk-scene/):

> “You never know what’s actually going to make it out into the world,” Markus explained. “We did have a scene illustrating more actively what the Hulk had been up to in terms of being a hero, as opposed to just starting it in the diner and explaining things. But it didn’t give you anything that you didn’t get from just sitting in the diner eating pancakes. And it came off more as noise than as content.”
>
> McFeely added. “It takes us forever to learn these things. But if the scene is not doing more than one thing, it’s probably not worthy of being in the movie.”

Comment: I just don't get it, why Russo gave so much praise to this scene which is basically an introduction for a Hulk in the Endgame. I'm sure there was a lot of material cut that was far more interesting than that. Oh well...

Comment: @RusI Both scenes serve the same purpose, the deleted and the cafe, since the movie is already too long, they decided to cut one of them.

Comment: If he said **Stark?**, then it'll be holy worthy including in the movie